# My data-selection won't display properly in the console after a button is clicked. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, console, dataset

I am in the middle of creating a rock paper scissors game and am trying to generate the player's selection based off of the button that was clicked. I'm trying to pull the selection name from the 'data-selection' attribute I placed in each of my button elements. With this script each time one of the buttons is clicked nothing displays in the console.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const selectionButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-selection]')
  const winnersChoice = document.getElementById('#winner')
  const loserChoice = document.getElementById('#loser')
  //Gives us our options to choose from.
  const options = [
    {
      name: 'rock',
      emoji:'&#128507;',
      beats: 'scissors'
    },
    {
      name: 'paper',
      emoji:'',
      beats: 'rock'
    },
    {
      name: 'scissors',
      emoji:'&#9986;',
      beats: 'paper'
    }
  ];

  //On button click
  $('button').click(function() {
    //Displays the chant 'Rock Paper Scissors Shoot!' when a button is clicked.
    $('#rock').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
    $('#paper').delay(1500).fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
    $('#scissors').delay(3000).fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
    $('#shoot').delay(4500).fadeIn('fast');
    //Generates the player's choice based off of the button they clicked.
    selectionButtons.forEach(selectionButton => {
      selectionButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const selectionName = selectionButton.dataset.selection
      makeSelection(selectionName)
    })
  })

    function makeSelection(selection) {
      console.log(selection)
    }
    //Generates the computer's seletion randomly.
    const computerSelection = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
  });
});
```

```css
/*Body*/
@import
  url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Big+Shoulders+Stencil+Display:wght@100&display=swap');

*{
  font-family: "Big Shoulders Stencil Display", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: #A80289;
}

/*Title*/
.game {
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

/*Buttons*/
.selections {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

button {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

.selection {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 100ms;
}

.selection:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

/*Chant*/
.chant {
  border: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#rock {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 49.4%
}

#paper {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 49%;
}

#scissors {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 48.14%;
}

#shoot {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 48.7%;
}

/*Scoreboards*/
.winner {
  height: 0;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, .2fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.winner-score {
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
  font-size: 75%;
}

.result-selection {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

#winner {
  font-size: 35px;
}

#loser {
  opacity: .5;
  font-size: 25px;
}

/*Media Queries*/
  /*Tablets and smaller*/
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .game {
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }

  .selection {
    font-size: 40px;
  }

  .chant {
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }

  #rock {
    position: relative;
    left: 48%
  }

  #paper {
    position: relative;
    left: 47.62%;
  }

  #scissors {
    position: relative;
    left: 45.7%;
  }

  #shoot {
    position: relative;
    left: 46.5%;
  }

  .winner {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

  /*Mobile*/
@media(max-width: 500px) {
  .game {
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }

  .selection {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  .chant {
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }

  #rock {
    position: relative;
    left: 47.26%
  }

  #paper {
    position: relative;
    left: 46.27%;
  }

  #scissors {
    position: relative;
    left: 43.19%;
  }

  #shoot {
    position: relative;
    left: 45%;
  }

  .winner {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" {IF CLASSES}class="classes"{/IF}>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Title-->
    <div class="game">
      <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
    </div>
    <!--Buttons-->
    <div class="selections">
      <button class="selection" data-selection="rock">&#128507;</button>
      <button class="selection" data-selection="paper"></button>
      <button class="selection" data-selection="scissors">&#9986;</button>
    </div>
    <!--Chant-->
    <h2 class="chant" hidden id="rock">Rock</h2>
    <h2 class="chant" hidden id="paper">Paper</h2>
    <h2 class="chant" hidden id=scissors>Scissors</h2>
    <h2 class="chant" hidden id="shoot">Shoot!</h2>
    <!--Scoreboards -->
    <div class="winner">
      <div>
        Player
        <span class="winner-score" data-your-score>0</span>
      </div>
      <div data-final-column>
        Computer
        <span class="winner-score" data-computer-score>0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="result-selection" hidden id="winner">&#9986;</div>
      <div class="result-selection" hidden id="loser"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've also tried it with this:

```js
  //On button click
  $('button').click(function() {
    //Displays the chant 'Rock Paper Scissors Shoot!' when a button is clicked.
    $('#rock').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
    $('#paper').delay(1500).fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
    $('#scissors').delay(3000).fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
    $('#shoot').delay(4500).fadeIn('fast');
    //Generates the player's choice based off of the button they clicked.
    selectionButtons.forEach(selectionButton => {
      const selectionName = selectionButton.dataset.selection
      makeSelection(selectionName)
  })

    function makeSelection(selection) {
      console.log(selection)
    }
```

But the console will display all three at the same time instead of only displaying the one that was selected. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're nesting a native click event handler within the jQuery click event handler for the same button elements. This is causing all kinds of confusion and odd behaviour on successive event occurrences.

To do what you require, simply get the reference to the clicked element using the `target` property of the event which is raised, and use `data()` to read the attribute required.

Note in the example below that I converted it to jQuery, as you're using an odd mix of jQuery and plain JS - it's best to stick to one. I also removed the extraneous code to do with fading in/out the elements which has issues, which I presume are to do with the redacted code in the question.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  const $selectionButtons = $('[data-selection]');

  $selectionButtons.on('click', e => {
    const selectionName = $(e.target).data('selection');
    makeSelection(selectionName)
  });
});


function makeSelection(selection) {
  console.log(selection)
}
```

```css
/*Body*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Big+Shoulders+Stencil+Display:wght@100&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: "Big Shoulders Stencil Display", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: #A80289;
}


/*Title*/

.game {
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}


/*Buttons*/

.selections {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

button {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

.selection {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 100ms;
}

.selection:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}


/*Chant*/

.chant {
  border: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#rock {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 49.4%
}

#paper {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 49%;
}

#scissors {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 48.14%;
}

#shoot {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 48.7%;
}


/*Scoreboards*/

.winner {
  height: 0;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, .2fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.winner-score {
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
  font-size: 75%;
}

.result-selection {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

#winner {
  font-size: 35px;
}

#loser {
  opacity: .5;
  font-size: 25px;
}


/*Media Queries*/


/*Tablets and smaller*/

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .game {
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }
  .selection {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .chant {
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }
  #rock {
    position: relative;
    left: 48%
  }
  #paper {
    position: relative;
    left: 47.62%;
  }
  #scissors {
    position: relative;
    left: 45.7%;
  }
  #shoot {
    position: relative;
    left: 46.5%;
  }
  .winner {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}


/*Mobile*/

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  .game {
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }
  .selection {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  .chant {
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }
  #rock {
    position: relative;
    left: 47.26%
  }
  #paper {
    position: relative;
    left: 46.27%;
  }
  #scissors {
    position: relative;
    left: 43.19%;
  }
  #shoot {
    position: relative;
    left: 45%;
  }
  .winner {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">

<div class="game">
  <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
</div>

<div class="selections">
  <button class="selection" data-selection="rock">&#128507;</button>
  <button class="selection" data-selection="paper"></button>
  <button class="selection" data-selection="scissors">&#9986;</button>
</div>

<h2 class="chant" hidden id="rock">Rock</h2>
<h2 class="chant" hidden id="paper">Paper</h2>
<h2 class="chant" hidden id=scissors>Scissors</h2>
<h2 class="chant" hidden id="shoot">Shoot!</h2>

<div class="winner">
  <div>
    Player
    <span class="winner-score" data-your-score>0</span>
  </div>
  <div data-final-column>
    Computer
    <span class="winner-score" data-computer-score>0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="result-selection" hidden id="winner">&#9986;</div>
  <div class="result-selection" hidden id="loser"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that works really well thank you! I'm trying to clean up the code to fade the chant in and out as smooth as possible while keeping everything in it's original position, but it won't be going away anytime soon